# Change text from "Submit" on input tag

Tags: html

I have a tag, `<input type="submit" class="like"/>`.
I want to have the text inside the button say "Like", but right now, it says "Submit".

`class="like"` is the CSS of the button, by the way.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

The `value` attribute on `submit`-type `<input>` elements controls the text displayed.

```
<input type="submit" class="like" value="Like" />
```

Comment: Excellent and to the point. Recommend also reading Quentin's answer below regarding use of `input` vs `button` when trying obtain the value of your element.

Answer (score 39):

The `value` attribute is used to determine the rendered label of a submit input.

```
<input type="submit" class="like" value="Like" />
```

Note that if the control is successful (this one won't be as it has no `name`) this will also be the submitted value for it.

To have a different submitted value and label you need to use a button element, in which the textNode inside the element determines the label. You can include other elements (including `<img>` here).

```
<button type="submit" class="like" name="foo" value="bar">Like</button>
```

Note that support for `<button>` is dodgy in older versions of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input name="submitBnt" type="submit" value="like"/>
```

name is useful when using `$_POST` in php and also in javascript as `document.getElementByName('submitBnt')`.
Also you can use name as a CS selector like `input[name="submitBnt"]`;
Hope this helps